# How to create profile update view without profile create view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Here I am trying to create profile update view , i haven't use profile create view in my views.py because that i am creating profile by signals so , i dont need profile create view but i need update view so that user can update his profile, i am getting an error  **ValueError at /profiles/profiles/admin/1/
The view profiles.views.ProfileUpdateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**  i dont know to fix it, here below is my code , If you think i am doing in very unprofessional way than please let me know and tell me the more professional way to do this.

views.py

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    refirect_field_name ='profiles:final_detail'
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    model = UserProfile

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        update_form = UserUpdateForm(instance = self.request.user)
        context['form']=update_form
        return context

    def form_valid(self,form):
            form.save()
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'profiles'

urlpatterns = [
    path('final/<str:username>/',FinalProfileDetailView.as_view(),name = 'final_detail'),
    path('profiles/<str:username>/<int:pk>/',ProfileUpdateView.as_view(),name = 'update'),
]
```

model.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name ='is_following',blank=True,)
    close_friends = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='my_close_friends', blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(("Avatar"), upload_to='displays', default = '1.jpg',height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank = True)
    background =models.ImageField(("Background"), upload_to='backgrounds', default = 'ak.jpg',height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank = True)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    
   
    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
    
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfile,self).save(*args, **kwargs) #it will take data and save it

        dp = Image.open(self.avatar.path) #storing avatar in varible
        if dp.height >300 or dp.width >300:
            output_size =(300,300) #set anysize you want
            dp.thumbnail(output_size) 
            dp.save(self.avatar.path) #after resing it save it in data base in place of uploaded once by user

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("userprofile_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

form.py

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ["username","email"]
```

user_update.html

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button type="submit" >save</button>
</form>
```

if more code or information is require than tell me in a comment session i will update my question with that information. Thank you!

Comment: Please share the `UserProfile` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have just shared that you can see now